# Algorithm do discovery number patterns

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching, logic, computation

Well, i must develop a software that can discovery a pattern in sequence of numbers, ex:

First Pattern: 
 10,20,30,40,50.. (The software must understand that numbers are always count +10).

Second Pattern:
 1,3,5 ... ( The software must understand that numbers are always odd).

So, the pattern is defined by user and the software must continue the sequence. Exists some algorithm wit this propose ?

PS: I'm thinking about I.A techniques, like BackPropagation or something else, but this is better solution ? Don't have a more easy solution ?

Comment: Unless you restrict yourself to certain types of sequences this is a very hard problem.

Comment: Are all patterns the same? (I mean, both examples are algebraic sequences, can they be of other kinds?)

Comment: Not @elyashiv, the pattern are always algebraic sequences (numbers).

Comment: sorry, I meant Arithmetic progression. Are they?

Comment: If you can assume an arithmetic sequence (constant difference), this problem is trivial

Comment: Given n numbers, you can always fit a polynomial of degree n-1 through these points. However, this not always the sequence you are after.

Comment: Unless you restrict yourself to specific types of sequences, *any* extension to a sequence is valid.

Answer (score 3):

To make an algorithm capable of learning anything, you need an [inductive bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_bias) that will restrict your search space to a smaller space, or makes your algorithm prefer some hypotheses over others.

The space of your search is the space of all the functions from integers to integers. This space is too wide to make a practical algorithm. You have to choose a smaller space.

See also the [Ugly duckling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ugly_duckling_theorem) and the [No free lunch theorem in search and optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_in_search_and_optimization).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you are given `a0, a1, ..., ak`. You can go for several patterns:

1. polynomial sequence, Ansatz `an = c0 + c1*n + c2*n^2 + ... + ck*n^k`: . Through the `k+1` points `(0,a0)`, `(1,a1)`, ... `(k,ak)` you can always fit a polynomial of degree `k`. Now that is not very interesting in the general case, but if the highest order coefficient(s) `ck` is zero, then the last sequence number `ak` fits to the polynomial defined by the previous sequence numbers. This way you can find odd numbers, square numbers, triangle numbers (1, 1+2, 1+2+3, ...) etc.
2. linear recursion, Ansatz `an = c0 + c1 * a(n-1) + ... + cm*a(n-m)`: You need `m+1` equations for a linear recursion of order `m`. This way you can find sequences like the Fibonacci numbers (`an = a(n-1) + a(n-2)`), but also geometric sequences (e.g. 1,2,4,8,...) and sequences like 1, 11, 111, ... (`an = 10*a(n-1)+1`). Here are the `m+1` equations:

   `am = c0 + c1 * a(m-1) + ... + cm*a0`

   `a(m+1) = c0 + c1 * am + ... + cm*a1` ...

   `a(2m) = c0 + c1 * a(2m-1) + ... + cm*am`

   So you can set `m=floor((k-1)/2)` s.t. `2m<k` and then check if the recursion also holds for `ak` and possibly `a(k-1)`.

There are other patterns, but these two are already very powerful and cover many cases.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can see is to write a function to check for every possible pattern and then output the once that return true. So you take the first value check how much is added and then check if the next one is equally bigger. Then check if the others follow said pattern. Do note that your first and second example would given this algorithm both have the same type of pattern (new value = last value + constant).

So in pseudoishcode your first function would look something like this:

```
  step=value[1]-value[0]
   for (value as i)
      if (value[i]-value[i-1]!=step)
         return false
return true
```

Next you might want to start looking for a way to detect primes which I would advice to search for as it's a common algorithm.

An alternative if you think there really are going to be nearly infinite possible sequences I suggest you look into [gennetic programming](http://www.genetic-programming.org/). And then use the number of matching numbers as fitness function of your program. However this only works if you have a very large number of available data points and might not even function at all. Another problem is that this way you will be unable to output the correct answer and merely be able to predict future answers.

Comment: Notice - you need to know all possible patterns.

Comment: This is impractical, i can't know all possible patterns. The are infinity.

Comment: How do you expect to detect patterns you don't even know about? For all we know the algorithm could be "the random numbers generated with seed 53213.

Comment: @user2776409 Can you enumerate them? If not, you're going to have a hard time. Polynomial sequences always fit finite amounts of sample points, but they don't always predict well.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the problems you suggest are linear, and therefore have solutions in the form

```
y = mx + c
```

For example, your first is `m==10, c==10` and your second is `m==2, c==1`.

Determining linear relationships like this is trivial to do, and using techniques to determine more complex relationships can be done, but teaching software what they "mean" (e.g. "odd numbers") is more-or-less impossible. For example, to find the "nature" of the relationship for

```
2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13
```

You would probably have to write a specific test with the relationship already in mind.

Comment: how about A.I (artificial intelligence techniques) ?

Comment: I added a bit about AI to my answer, be warned that this might not work as well as you expect trough.

Comment: Depends what you mean by AI. Machine learning techniques could be useful, but require training data sets and won't be able to identify arbitrary relationships out of the scope of the training.